# Tomcat server behaving differently when it run as windows service and through command prompt

Tags: java, windows, swing, tomcat, service

I observed a strange behavior of Tomcat when it run as a windows service and when it is up by startup.bat file through command prompt. The problem is I have used AWT (SWING JFileChooser also) FileDialog of java for getting a browsing window for choosing a file in our web application. The browsing window is coming as a pop up when i run the tomcat through cmd, where as it is not coming when i run tomcat as a service. Could you please tell me why I am facing this problem and the solution for this. I would appreciate your time and efforts. Thank you in advance for you help.

Comment: Do you see any kind of exceptions in the server log when the window does not pop up?

Comment: Hi Bot .. thanks for your quick reply .. i dont see any exception.

Comment: Are you referring to different versions of Java when starting from cmd and when starting tomcat as a service? The reason why I am asking is that I remember facing an issue in the past where users complained that some screens did not pop up on certain versions of JRE/JDK.

Comment: I am using latest version of java 8 and the path is set in environment variables. so in both the ways it should point to same jre/jdk.

Comment: My worry is as i mentioned in post why im able to see the browsing window in one case but not in other case. I mean to say browsing window is coming when i run tomcat from cmd.